# Foreman finish template is not getting resolve when user-data of the image is enabled

Tags: amazon-ec2, provisioning, theforeman

I am using Foreman 1.6 and using AWS EC2 as compute resource.
Problem is, Foreman could not able to resolve the finish template when the user-data of image is enabled. And, I could not able to provision the VM.

When user-date of image is disabled, foreman able to resolve the finish-template and able to provision the vm (Without reading the template, i.e puppet client installation).
Could you guide me where I am going wrong? Its been two week I am struggling with this issue.

Thanks,
Sekhar

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a new provisioning script of type "user-data" (or just use the "Kickstart default user data" and associate it to your OS. Finish scripts are not the right "kind" for cloud-init.